# PHPStorm HTML Formatting comments

Tags: html, css, phpstorm

I have a list of `li` and encountered the dreaded space between inline block elements. My quick fix is to utilize the comment trick, all works well but once I format the code with PHPStorm the comments are no longer being placed correctly. Is there anyway I can configure this in PHPStorm? An example of what happens is shown below.

```html
<li>Hello</li><!--
--><li>Second</li>
```

What ends up happening is

```html
<li>Hello</li>
<!--
          -->
<li>Second</li>
```

Comment: Sorry I think I'm missing something. What is the _"comment trick"_?...

Comment: Hi, this is what I am referring to. http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

i'm aware that there are other tricks for my issue but upon reading the comments I feel like the comment trick is the most sturdy and less hacky technique and has worked. It should work great when coupled along with PHPStorm's powerful IDE abilities but I can't get the right settings to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest disabling formatting for such blocks, like:

```
<!--@formatter:off-->
<li>Hello</li><!--
--><li>Second</li>
<!--@formatter:on-->
```

You would also need to make sure to enable formatter markers in `Settings/Editor/Code Style`, `Enable formatter markers in comments`